# Just display notification and background app stay onResume

Tags: android, android-tv

I have scenario where I want to develop an app on TV, in that if user is watching some videos on Youtube and if I want to load my app, then it will launch in foreground and I will display some information with transparent background and behind app will continue to work, like if behind app is Youtube then it should play as it is without pause.

Please help me if it is possible? if yes then how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

> In Manifest Define Activity theme as transulent :

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

> For Transulent Activity life cycle differs from Non-transulent Activity :
>
> For Non-transulent Activity-A if any other Activity-B comes on top of
>   it then Activity-A will be in onStop state.
>
> Activity-A if any other Activity-B comes on top of it then Activity-A
>   will be in onPause stateBut where as For Transulent

Then do this :

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      if (mVideoView.isPlaying()) {
        // Argument equals true to notify the system that the activity
        // wishes to be visible behind other translucent activities
        if (! requestVisibleBehind(true)) {
          // App-specific method to stop playback and release resources
          // because call to requestVisibleBehind(true) failed
          stopPlayback();
        }
      } else {
        // Argument equals false because the activity is not playing
        requestVisibleBehind(false);
      }
    }
```

> I did implementation it worked go through this it will help u for sure
>   :

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/playback/options.html

> If you requirement is related to Picture in Picture try this :

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html

Comment: You are right Jeelan, but I don't want to run my app in background instead I want to play continue other apps like Youtube, like if my app launch other app work still as it is working without onPause or onStop mode

Comment: Above description is meant for that only provided app like Youtube or other should have the implementation - > For example Video is playing in foreground  using remote u launched your App that should be transparent then only background app will have an ability to play video.Conclusion is ur Activity theme should be Transparent.